# Basemap functions about plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this problem when I try to put the satellite picture above of the `basemap`. Can someone help me to put the satellite picture above the `basemap`?

Code:

```
    import os
    os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = r'C:\Users\mateu\anaconda3\Library\share\proj'
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

    from netCDF4 import Dataset

    ncd_file = Dataset('C:/Users/mateu/Desktop/python aula/S5P_OFFL_L2__NO2____20200108T153448_20200108T171618_11595_01_010302_20200110T083056.nc', 'r')

    lat = ncd_file.groups['PRODUCT'].variables['latitude'][0, :, :]
    lon = ncd_file.groups['PRODUCT'].variables['longitude'][0, :, :]

    no2_data = ncd_file.groups['PRODUCT'].variables['nitrogendioxide_tropospheric_column'][0, :, :]

    fill_value = ncd_file.groups['PRODUCT'].variables['nitrogendioxide_tropospheric_column']._FillValue
    fill_val = fill_value*1000000

    no2_em = np.array(no2_data)*1000000

    no2_em[no2_em == fill_val] = np.nan

    no2_data = no2_em
    from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

    def make_map():
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        m = Basemap(projection='merc', llcrnrlat=-35, urcrnrlat=7,
                    llcrnrlon=-77, urcrnrlon=-32, resolution='l')

        m.ax = ax
        m.fillcontinents()
        return fig, m

    def drawstates(ax, shapefile=r'C:\Users\mateu\Desktop\python aula\i3geomap_limitesmunicipais'):
            shp = m.readshapefile(shapefile, 'states', drawbounds=True)
            for nshape, seg in enumerate(m.states):
                poly = Polygon(seg, facecolor='0.75', edgecolor='k')
                ax.add_patch(poly)
            cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('jet')
            cmap.set_under('w')

            m.pcolormesh(lon, lat, no2_data, latlon = True, vmin = 0 , vmax = 100, cmap = cmap)

    fig, m = make_map()
    drawstates(m.ax)
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M61t.png here is the picture's link

Comment: Please check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to make your example minimal.